# c# convert.ToInt not working?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have been trying to figure this out for an hour now and have tried parsing but hasnt worked. The code below keeps giving me the error Input string not in correct format on the two lines where i convert leagueData[2] and league data[3]. Am I missing something simple ?

```
  public static void readLeagues(string theFile, ArrayList allLeagues)
    {
        StreamReader inLeagues = null;
        bool anyMoreLeagues = false;
        string[] leagueData = new string[frmLeagues.numLeagueItems];
        string[] fixtureData = new string[frmLeagues.numFixItems];
        Leagues tempLeague;
        Fixtures tempFix;
        int numFixInLeague, leaguePrize;

        if (fileOpenForReadOK(theFile, ref inLeagues))
        {

            anyMoreLeagues = getNext(frmLeagues.numLeagueItems, inLeagues, leagueData);

            while (anyMoreLeagues == true)
            {
               leaguePrize = Convert.ToInt32(leagueData[2]);
               numFixInLeague = Convert.ToInt32(leagueData[3]);


                tempLeague = new Leagues(leagueData[0], leagueData[1],numFixInLeague,
                                        leaguePrize);

                for (int i = 0; i < numFixInLeague; i++)
                {
                    getNext(frmLeagues.numFixItems, inLeagues, fixtureData);
                    tempFix = new Fixtures(fixtureData[0], fixtureData[1], fixtureData[2]
                                            , fixtureData[3], fixtureData[4]);
                    tempLeague.addFixturesToLeague(tempLeague.getLeagueFixtures(),tempFix);

                }

                allLeagues.Add(tempLeague);
                anyMoreLeagues = getNext(frmLeagues.numLeagueItems, inLeagues, leagueData);
            }
        }
        if (inLeagues != null) inLeagues.Close();
```

Below is the code for the League ClassThanks, Jack

class Leagues
    {
        private string LeagueName;
        private string LeagueSponsor;
        private int LeaguePrize;
        private int LeagueNumFixtures;
        ArrayList LeagueFixtures;

```
    public Leagues(string inLeagueName, string inLeagueSponsor, int inLeaguePrize,
                    int inLeagueNumFixtures)
    {
        LeagueName = inLeagueName;
        LeagueSponsor = inLeagueSponsor;
        LeaguePrize = inLeaguePrize;
        LeagueNumFixtures = inLeagueNumFixtures;
        LeagueFixtures = new ArrayList();

    }
    public ArrayList addFixturesToLeague(ArrayList fixturesSoFar, Fixtures theNewFixture)
    {
        fixturesSoFar.Add(theNewFixture);
        LeagueNumFixtures = fixturesSoFar.Count;
        return fixturesSoFar;

    }
    public void setLeagueName(string inLeagueName)
    {
        LeagueName = inLeagueName;
    }
    public void setLeagueSponsor(string inLeagueSponsor)
    {

        LeagueSponsor = inLeagueSponsor;
    }
    public void setLeaguePrize(int inLeaguePrize)
    {
        LeaguePrize = inLeaguePrize;
    }
    public void setLeagueNumofFixture(int inLeagueNumFixtures)
    {
        LeagueNumFixtures = inLeagueNumFixtures;
    }
    public void setLeagueFixtures(ArrayList inLeagueFix)
    {
        LeagueFixtures = inLeagueFix;
    }
    public string getLeagueName()
    {
        return LeagueName;
    }
    public string getLeagueSponsor()
    {
        return LeagueSponsor;
    }
    public int getLeaguePrize()
    {
        return LeaguePrize;
    }
    public int getLeagueNumFixtures()
    {
        return LeagueNumFixtures;
    }
    public ArrayList getLeagueFixtures()
    {
        return LeagueFixtures;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do leagueData[2] and leagueData[3] contain?

Comment: league data[2] contains league prize money and leaguedata[3] contains the number of fixtures within the league. Both are stored as int during the getset and then put into an array list and then it doenst compile

Comment: You can't convert a variable that contains nothing. I think what Marty was asking is, _do the variables actually have a value_ before you try to convert them?

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure that leagueData[2] and leagueData[3] are not null, and then do a TryParse on them. You should also first check that leagueData is not null or empty. I'm assuming leagueData is an array of strings

```
var prize = leagueData[2];
int outNum;
int leaguePrize = Int.TryParse(prize, out outNum)? outNum : 0;
```

- couple small edits per phoog's comment

Comment: You don't need to call string.IsNullOrEmpty -- if you pass a null or empty string to TryParse, it will just return false, same as with any invalid string.  Also it's not necessary to initialize the outNum variable, as the call to TryParse assigns a value to the variable.